# Find all the idempotent elements of $\Bbb Z[i]/(5)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to find all the idempotent elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$. The four idempotent elements are $3+i$, $3-i$, $0$, and $1$, but the solution I have does not explain how these elements were found. I understand the definition of idempotent elements ($e^2=e$) and know how to confirm that these elements are idempotent elements. The trivial solutions are obvious, but I have no idea how to go about finding the nontrivial $3+i$ and $3-i$ solutions.

If anyone could help me understand how $3+i$ and $3-i$ were found and if possible why they along with $0$ and $1$ are the only solutions I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Z[i] being the Gaussian Integers and (5) being the principal ideal generated by 5.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, all of them were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't find them if you already know them. You simply show the computation. The ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/(5)$ basically works like computation with integers and i, but every time you see a 5 or a multiple of 5 you can make it zero. For instance, $(2-3i)^2 = 4 - 12i - 9 = -5 - 12i = -2i = 3i$. Note that in the last equation, I was allowed to change the number by a multiple of 5. You'll probably need to use a fact like that in the calculation.

As far as how they found those particular solutions, a typical element of the ring looks like $a + bi$. So $(a+bi)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2abi$. If this is idempotent, then in the ring $\mathbb{Z}/(5)$ we must have $a,b$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = a$ and $2ab = b$. If $b$ is not zero, then $2a = 1$, and so $a = 3$. (This is because $6 = 1$.) Then we know $3^2 + b^2 = 3$, so $b^2 = 1$ and we have $b = \pm 1$. If $b$ is zero, then we need $a^2 = a$, which has only solutions $a = 0,1$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible way, which is mostly algebraic: consider $e=a+bi$.

In order for $e$ to be idempotent, we must have $e^2-e \equiv 0 \mod 5$ (using $\mod 5$ in the loose sense in that the components of $e^2-e$ must be divisible by $5$).

Then this means that $(a+bi)^2-(a+bi) = (a^2-a-b^2) + i(2ab-b)$ must have its real and imaginary parts divisible by $5$, or that $a^2-a -b^2 \equiv 0 \mod 5$ and $2ab-b \equiv0 \mod 5$.

- Case 1: $b \equiv 0 \mod 5$

Then clearly the second equation is satisfied, and we're left with $a^2-a \equiv 0 \mod 5 \implies a \equiv 0, 1 \mod 5$. Then our solution is either $e=0+0i$ or $e=1+0i$.

- Case 2: $b \not\equiv 0 \mod 5$

Then clearly we may cancel $b$ from the second equation (as it possesses an inverse modulo $5$), leaving us with $2a-1 \equiv 0 \mod 5 \implies a \equiv 3 \mod 5$. Going to the first equation yields $1 \equiv b^2 \mod 5 \implies b \equiv \pm 1 \mod 5$. Then our solution is either $e=3+i$ or $e=3-i$.

This should account for all the solutions, which matches with the answers you obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\;a+bi\in\Bbb Z[i]\;$, then

$$(a+bi)^2+(5)=a+bi+(5)\iff (a^2-b^2-a)+b(2a-1)\in (5)$$

We have that either

$$5\mid b\;\;\wedge\;\;5\mid (a^2-a)\iff a=0\pmod 5\;\;\vee\;\;a=1\pmod 5$$

or else

$$5\mid (2a-1)\iff a=3\pmod 5\;\;\wedge\;\;5\mid(a^2-a-b^2)\iff b=\pm 1\pmod 5$$

In the first case we get $\;0+(5)=(5)\;,\;\;1+(5)\;$, and in the second one we get $\;(3\pm i)+(5)\;$ , just as you mention.